# Select rows and remove duplicate based on value of a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, duplicates

I have the following query:

```
select "houses"."id", 
"houses"."uuid", 
COUNT(1) OVER() as full_count from "houses" 
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(houses.types) house_types 
inner join "hoods" on "hoods"."id" = "houses"."hood_id" and "hoods"."owner_id" = 2 
inner join "groups" on "groups"."hood_id" = "hoods"."id" and "groups"."manager_id" = 54 
where house_types->>'type' = 'big' 
group by "houses"."id", "houses"."uuid" 
order by lower(houses.name) asc 
limit 20
```

Which properly gives me the first 20 houses which has a type 'big' that are in the hood which owner_id is 2 AND which hood has an associated group which manager is 54.

Now, the problem is that sometimes I will have houses which name will be the same, and I want to just keep one of those and removing the rest. So for example:

If my houses table looks like:

```
id, types, name
1, [{ type: 'rating' }], 'white house'
2, [{ type: 'rating' }], 'white house'
3, [{ type: 'rating' }], 'red house'
```

I would just get the rows with id 1 and 3.

What is a good way to do that in PostgreSQL assuming that I can have both offsets and limits applied to the query, and I want to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `group by`, use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (lower(h.name)) h.id, h.uuid
      COUNT(*) OVER() as full_count
from houses h cross join lateral
     jsonb_array_elements(h.types) ht inner join
     "hoods" ho
     on ho.id = h.hood_id and
        ho.owner_id = 2 inner join
     "groups" g
     on g.hood_id = ho.id and
        g.manager_id = 54 
where house_types->>'type' = 'big' 
order by lower(houses.name) asc  
limit 20;
```

Edit:

```
select h.*, count(*) over ()  as full_count
from (select distinct on (lower(h.name)) h.id, h.uuid
      from houses h cross join lateral
           jsonb_array_elements(h.types) ht inner join
           "hoods" ho
           on ho.id = h.hood_id and
              ho.owner_id = 2 inner join
           "groups" g
           on g.hood_id = ho.id and
              g.manager_id = 54 
      where house_types->>'type' = 'big' 
      order by lower(houses.name) asc  
     ) h
limit 20
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Why do you need both lower(h.name) and h.id and houses.uuid in the DISTINCT ON, if we just want them to be distinct by name?

Comment: @HommerSmith . . . I think you are right.  That is not needed.

Comment: Gordon, there is a problem with this approach. Even though the distinct ON works, the COUNT(*) OVER() is still counting the removed rows. How can I have both distinct ON and count over all the results using the window function so I can properly know all the potential unique rows that exist besides the limit?

Comment: @HommerSmith . . . I would recommend a subquery with `distinct on` to reduce the number of rows.  Then use the `count()` window function.

Comment: What do you mean a subquery with DISTINCT ON? I was thinking on actually having a subquery that would do the COUNT. Do you mind expanding your answer?

Comment: Shouldn't the limit be in the subquery?

Comment: @HommerSmith . . . Only if you want a maximum value of 20.